# Postgresql hash partition scaling

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, data-partitioning

I have 10 partitions of a hash partitioned table and I want to increase this number.

What is the best way to do it ? Should I have to remove the 10 tables and recreate all of the new ones ?

I want 20 hash partitions now.

Comment: Yes, you have to start over: create a new partitioned table and copy all the data. But why don't you leave it as it is, with 10 partitions? Do you have more than 10 disks and want to spread I/O?

Comment: Ok thx, and to start over if I delete the main table, child will be destroyed too or I ll have to delete them one by one ?

Comment: All childs will be dropped when you drop the parent table. Just give it a try

Comment: So this is possible to add new child with different modulus, but it is not the perfect way:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html?spm=a2c65.11461447.0.0.1a6b7fc7P4r0QU